# Trap all accesses to an address range (Linux)

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, mmap, signal-handling

#### Background

I'm writing a framework to enable co-simulation of RTL running in a simulator and un-modified host software.  The host software is written to control actual hardware and typically works in one of two ways:

1. Read/Write calls through a driver
2. Memory mapped access using mmap

The former case is pretty straightforward - write a library that implements the same read / write calls as the driver and link against that when running a simulation.  This all works wonderfully and I can run un-modified production software as stimulus for my RTL simulations.

The second case is turning out to be far more difficult than the first...

#### Trapping mmap

Initially I thought I could use `LD_PRELOAD` to intercept the mmap call.  In my implementation of `mmap` I'd  allocate some page-aligned memory and then `mprotect` it and set a signal handler to trap `SIGSEGV`.

There are numerous problems with this approach:

*Read vs Write*

I can determine the address of the access from `siginfo_t->si_addr` but not whether the access was read or write.

*Catching repeat accesses*

In the signal handler I need to un-protect the memory region, otherwise the I'll get repeat `SIGSEGV`s as soon as my handler exits and the host code can never continue.  However if I unprotect the region then my signal handler won't trap subsequent accesses.

*Signal handler nastiness*

To block in a signal handler while the simulator drives the RTL and returns a result  violates all sorts of programming rules - particularly given the simulator could trigger all sorts of other events and execute arbitrary code before returning a result from this access.

#### Other approaches

I was wondering if it's possible to create a file-like object that behaves like a disk rather than using `mprotect` on a buffer.  I haven't found any information suggesting this is feasible.

#### Questions

Is it possible to trap all accesses to an mmap region and how?

- Accesses need to block for an indeterminate period of time (while simulator runs)
- Read accesses need to retrieve a new value placed by my trap

Assuming `LD_PRELOAD` and `mprotect` is the best route:

- Can I determine whether the access was a read or a write call?
- How do I trap subsequent accesses since I have to un-`mprotect` the region?

#### Related Questions

[How to write a signal handler to catch SIGSEGV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663456/write-a-signal-handler-to-catch-sigsegv)

[Possible to trap write to address (x86 - linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608584/possible-to-trap-write-to-address-x86-linux)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On X86 you can set Trap flag for the caller's context to get SIGTRAP after one instruction (this flag is typically used for single-stepping). That is, when SIGSEGV is encountered, you set TF in the caller's EFLAGS (see `ucontext.h`), enable reading with `mprotect` and return. If SIGSEGV is repeated instantly with the same IP, you enable writing (and optionally disable reading, if you want to distinguish read-modify-write from write-only access). If you get SIGSEGV from the same IP for read-only and write-only protection, enable read-write.

Whenever you get SIGTRAP, you can analyze what value was written (if it was a write access), and you can also re-protect the page to trap future accesses.

Correction: if both reads and writes can have side-effects, try write-only protection first, then apply reading side-effects and try read-only protection, then enable writing and handle side-effects of writing in the final SIGTRAP handler.

**UPDATE:** I was deadly wrong on recommending hypothetical write-only protection which turns out not to exist on most architectures. Fortunately there's a more straightforward way to know whether the operation that failed tries to read memory, at least on x86:

Page fault exception pushes an error code to the stack, which is available in Linux SIGSEGV handler as the `err` member of `sigcontext` structure. [Bit 1 of the error code](http://wiki.osdev.org/Paging#Handling) is 1 for *write* faults and 0 otherwise. For read-modify-write operation, it will be 0 initially (here you can emulate reading, knowing exactly that it's going to happen).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Note that X86 doesn't support write-only protection (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18829341/579887).  Unfortunately it looks like I'll have to perform a speculative read into the simulator every `SIGSEGV` which will be inefficient for writes (and may make the modelled behaviour different to real hardware)

Comment: @Chiggs, I can't believe that I was silly enough to invent this "write-only" nonsense. Fortunately, there *is* a solution (exception error code that gets also into `sigcontext->err` contains r/w bit). See update in the answer.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko -- could you please elaborate on how to set the TF in the caller's EFLAGS? Is this done inside the SIGSEGV handler by (1) calling `swapcontext()` to swap to the `uc_link` context, (2) setting the TF flag (via inline asm), (3) swapping back to the original SIGSEGV handler context, and (4) enabling read via `mprotect()`? I'm unclear what the "caller context" is inside the SIGSEGV handler.

Comment: @cklin In linux, caller's EFLAGS are in `...->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_EFL]` (see `sys/ucontext.h` for related definitions). AFAIK you need no swapping and no use of `uc_link`, just set TF in gregs[REG_EFL].

Comment: @cklin There's a (messy) example of my experimentation [here](https://github.com/potentialventures/cocotb/blob/Issue%23118/lib/mmap/mmap_preload.c), but in summary: `ucontext_t *c = context; c->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_EFL] |= X86_EFLAGS_TF;` worked for me, no need to call `swapcontext()` since it's passed to your handler.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. Note that `REG_EFL`, `REG_ERR` are only defined when `_GNU_SOURCE` is defined on my Ubuntu system. `REG_ERR` is array index of the write flag mentioned in the answer.