# Finding function that access physical memory addresses

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am debugging a new hardware prototype on CentOS7 linux on intel xeon based server. 
In the logic analyzer traces, there are some accesses to memory physical address that of my interest and would like to know which functions in linux kernel triggers this access.

Is there any way we can find out the related function that accesses that range of physical address?

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19725900/watch-a-variable-memory-address-change-in-linux-kernel-and-print-stack-trace)

Comment: and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608584/possible-to-trap-write-to-address-x86-linux)